# Safe casting in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is there anything like C++s safe casts in Objective-C?

I know that they are in Objective C++, but I am unsure about possible side effects. Using Objective C++ may slow compilation time - are there any other reasons not to use it?

Comment: What was the error, and what was the cast? If the cast was casting an object to a different type (i.e. from `id` to `NSString *`), it may affect how the compiler chooses what selector to use if there is more than one selector with different signatures.

Comment: You can't use `dynamic_cast` in this case (target is not pointer or reference to **class**). Use `static_cast` instead.

Comment: I was accidentally casting a NSUInteger to a unsigned int instead of a unsigned long

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objective-c does have C++ safe casts. Alternatively, we can use runtime reflection:

```
id myOb=[someObject getObject];
NSAssert([myOb isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]], @"Return value is not of type MyClass as expected.");
MyClass * newOb= (MyClass *)myOb;
```

References:

[Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/8-confusing-objective-c-warnings-and.html):

Comment: Casting of id myObj to MyClass* is redundant. Ids can be freely assigned to variables of any object type.

Comment: "Objective-c does have C++ safe casts". What do you mean? e.g. dynamic_cast or so? It does not compile. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which feature of C++ do you think will help you cast a 64-bit `long` to a 32-bit `int`?

Comment: In many compiler implementations `long` is 32-bit even on 64-bit target. And `long long` is 64-bit.

Comment: Not in unix or OS X.  The compiler should give you a good warning about that.

Comment: This should have been a comment - not an answer. The casting was a mistake - I believe that I would have received a warning if I was using a C++ cast

Comment: You will get a warning when you try to assign a 64-bit long to a 32-bit int. You use a static cast precisely to get rid of that warning. By using a static cast you're telling the compiler that you know what you're doing.  Whether you use a plain old C cast or a c++ static_cast the result is the same.

Comment: Anyway, even if the motivation for asking about safe casts is incorrect, the question is still one I'd like to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on compiler flags to warn you in cases like this. This particular mistake would be caught by the -Wconversion flag.

Comment: -Wconversion seems to miss the error and raise a lot of spurious errors instead